# Time required to build a pyramid

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $45$ people can built $1/2$ of a pyramid in $288$ days, how many days would it take $65$ people to build the next $1/6$ the pyramid, rounded to nearest integer, assuming each person works at the same constant rate?

Question: what the term "next $1/6$ the pyramid" mean? is it, $1/6$ of the $1/2$ of the pyramid, or $1/6$ of the full pyramid?

Comment: I think it means " the next one sixth of the whole pyramid". At least that is what I'd understand if someone would be telling me this story.

Comment: It is not clear what is meant by "1/2 of a pyramid". Do they mean 1/2 of the height, or 1/2 of the volume, or 1/2 of the total energy needed to stack the pieces?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter "Half of someting" usually means exactly that. If I say "I've done already half my homework, one wouldn't usually ask "half of the mathematics homework, the history homework or the grammatic homework".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each person does $\;\frac{\frac12}{45}=\frac1{90}\;$ of a pyramid in $288$ days, which means each persons does $\;\frac{\frac1{90}}{288}=\frac1{25,920}\;$ of a pyramid in one day.

Thus, $\;65\;$ persons do $\;65\cdot\frac1{25,920}=\frac{13}{5184}\;$ of the pyramid every day, so if it will take them $\;k\;$ days to complete one sixth of the pyramid:

$$\frac{13k}{5,184}=\frac16\implies k=\frac{5,184}{78}=66.46\cong66$$